# "display_results undefined" error and I cannot figure out why. I'm new to programming

Tags: python-3.x

here is my code, I'm not sure what I can do. every time I try to run this code, no matter what I've changed I get hung up at the same spot: "builtins.NameError: name 'hourly_pay' is not defined"  I've marked in the code where which line it's in; where I try to define "display_results"

```
def main():
    display_message()

    #Get name
    employee_name=input("Enter employee's name: ")

    #Get Sales 
    sales_amount = float(input("Enter the sales amount: "))

    #Get Hours
    hours_worked = int(input("Enter hours worked by this employee: "))

    #Calculate Hourly Pay
    hourly_pay = hours_worked * hourly_pay_rate

    #Calculate Commission
    commission = sales_amount * commission_rate

    #Calculate Gross Pay
    gross_pay = hourly_pay + commission_rate

    #Calculate Witholding 
    witholding = gross_pay * witholding_rate

    #Calculate Net Pay
    net_pay = gross_pay -witholding 
    display_results = (hourly_pay, commission, gross_pay, witholding, net_pay)

def display_message():
    print('This program uses functions to calculate pay, commission, gross')
    print('pay, witholding, and net pay.')

def display_results():
    print('Hourly pay amount is: ' (hourly_pay))   #<-- This is where it errors  
    print('commission amount is: ' (commission))     
    print('Gross pay amount is: ' (gross_pay))    
    print('Witholding amount is:' (witholding))       
    print('Net pay amount is:' (net_pay))


hourly_pay_rate = 7.5
commission_rate = 0.05
witholding_rate = 0.25


main()    
display_results()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to reference global variable inside the local scope which will fail. Also you are trying to auto type cast the str to int. The correct way to do this is show below:

### Solution

Use `global` keyword to refer to global scope variable. Also [Refer to Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) on global vs local scope variables.

```
def main():
    global hourly_pay

    display_message()

    #Get name
    employee_name=input("Enter employee's name: ")

    #Get Sales 
    sales_amount = float(input("Enter the sales amount: "))

    #Get Hours
    hours_worked = int(input("Enter hours worked by this employee: "))

    #Calculate Hourly Pay
    hourly_pay = hours_worked * hourly_pay_rate

    #Calculate Commission
    commission = sales_amount * commission_rate

    #Calculate Gross Pay
    gross_pay = hourly_pay + commission_rate

    #Calculate Witholding 
    witholding = gross_pay * witholding_rate

    #Calculate Net Pay
    net_pay = gross_pay -witholding 
    display_results = (hourly_pay, commission, gross_pay, witholding, net_pay)

def display_message():
    print('This program uses functions to calculate pay, commission, gross')
    print('pay, witholding, and net pay.')

def display_results():
    global hourly_pay
    print('Hourly pay amount is: {}'.format(hourly_pay))
    # print('commission amount is: ' (commission))
    # print('Gross pay amount is: ' (gross_pay))
    # print('Witholding amount is:' (witholding))
    # print('Net pay amount is:' (net_pay))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    hourly_pay = 0.00
    commission = 0.00
    gross_pay = 0.00
    witholding = 0.00
    net_pay = 0.00

    hourly_pay_rate = 7.5
    commission_rate = 0.05
    witholding_rate = 0.25

    main()
    display_results()
```

Let us know if this solves your problem or not. I have tried it myself and returns 15.0 as output.

Comment: This defiantly helps! I tried your code (thank you by the way) and it produced an output for "Hourly pay amount is:" but what can I do to get an output for the others? (commission, gross pay amount, witholding, and net pay amount?) and one other thing, how might I get this on a loop to say do it for multiple employees?

Comment: That's upto you, I have shown you how it's done. You can tweak this code such that it gets executed in a loop. Basically you have have to ask user whether another record is to be calculated or not and shown the inputs based on the response from the user. Hope you got the idea.

Comment: I'm getting the concept, I will continue to mess with it to get exactly what I want. Thank you so much for your help, I've been struggling with this for five days now...

Comment: Glad to help :)